# Jython - Integration Java and Python

Tags: java, python, jython, jython-2.7

I have sample python file, which i need to call through java program.
For this is am using `Jython`.

**Pom Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.python</groupId>
    <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Java File**

public class JythonIntegrationTest {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException , ScriptException {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();

        context.setWriter(writer);
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("python");
        engine.eval(new FileReader("D:\\python\\sample.py") , context);
        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    }
}
```

when i run this program, i get below error :-

line is - `manager.getEngineByName("python");`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at maven_test.maven_test.JythonIntegrationTest.main(JythonIntegrationTest.java:38)
```

Do i need to run some python exe/service on system.

Comment: Try changing your jython-standalone dependency version to `2.7.1b2`.

Comment: There is a 2.7.1b3 version as well.